# How can I achieve Excel/SharePoint filtering in Infragistics grid?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I'm using Infragistics grid and want to filter results. The filter supported by the grid filters based on the text entered, but I want to filter based on a list of checkboxes, like in Excel and SharePoint. How can I achieve this effect??

[image]

SharePoint list filters based on which checkboxes are checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the `igGrid` filtering drop down with your own custom filtering conditions as shown in this [sample](http://www.igniteui.com/grid/custom-conditions-filtering).

```
{
    name: "Filtering",
    mode: "simple",
    filterDialogContainment: "window",
    columnSettings: [
    {
        columnKey: "Country",
        customConditions: {
           USA: {
                key: 'USA',
                labelText: 'USA',
                expressionText: "USA",
                filterFunc: filterCountryUSA
           },
           Canada:{
                 key: 'Canada',
                 labelText: 'Canada',
                 expressionText: "Canada",
                 filterFunc: filterCountryCanada
           },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but the problem is that you have to enter these static. I was looking for a solution that updates dynamically the custom conditions based on the column's data.